# Data not coming to ListBox after query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2000

I have a ListBox on .aspx web page in which I am trying to fetch the data from the DB. The query is in the form of a stored procedure and the following is the `ListBind(string queryPart)` method that I am using.

```
private void ListBind(string queryPart)
{
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Retrieve", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
                 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                 adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@s1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = queryPart;
                 adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@s2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                 adp.Fill(ds);
                 ListBox1.DataSource = ds;
                 ListBox1.DataBind();
}
```

The problem is that I do not get any data into my ListBox and it remains empty, with no errors. Tried to find my putting breakpoints but couldn't find the reason.

I have a similar method which uses a diferent procedure without parameters to bind another dropdown list in my webpage and is working fine. So, something is wrong here. Any suggestions?

Comment: I know this is obvious but are you sure your query is not returning a empty set? Just wanting to make sure the problem is in the code. (Really would like to make this a comment more than a answer)

Comment: Are you saying that you added a breakpoint inside ListBind and it wasn't hit? If so, are you sure that ListBind is being called? It's not inside a !Page.IsPostBack or something is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SQL profiler to watch the procedure invocation to see what parameters you're actually using and then try running it directly in SSMS. Equally just break after assigning the parameters.

But I'd bet it's the selected item parameter - you may want to look at one of the other "selected" properties (eg SelectedValue) if it isn't populated.

Comment: I was trying to look for SQL Profiler but is this available in SSMS Express?

Comment: No it isn't. So just use the debug approach. If you have any problem doing that you can write out the content to a temporary control on the page.

Comment: For SQL Express use this for profiling https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change it to below and try?

```
private void ListBind(string queryPart)
{
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Retrieve", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                 adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("s1",queryPart);
                 adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("s2",DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
                 adp.Fill(dt);
                 ListBox1.DataSource = dt ;
                 ListBox1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether a DataSet can be given as a DataSource to a control. Can you try again by changing the code to something like this

```
 ListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
 ListBox1.DataBind();
```